# Is there the opposite function for evm_increaseTime?

Tags: solidity, testrpc

I'm using the following function in my JS tests (with truffle) to move forward in time to test time dependent functions:

```
const timeTravel = function (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      method: "evm_increaseTime",
      params: [time], // 86400 is num seconds in day
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, result) => {
      if(err){ return reject(err) }
      return resolve(result)
    });
  })
}
```

So then, I can do a test like this:

```
it("should not allow to buy tokens if crowdsale has finished", async function () {

    await timeTravel(100000) // Move forward in time so the crowdsale has finished
    await mineBlock() // workaround for https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/336

    try {
      await crowdsale.buyTokens(accounts[1],{from:accounts[1],value:1 * 10 ** 18});
    } catch (e) {
      return true;
    }
    throw new Error("I should never see this!")


  });
```

The problem is that this "time traveling to the future" is not transitory, meaning that testrpc will continue to be in a future block unless I stop testrpc and start it again.

I'd like to run a test in the future and then go back to continue running the automated test in the current block.

Supplying a negative number will obviously not go back to a previous block and there is no such thing as evm_decreaseTime.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a snapshot of the EVM at the beginning of your test and revert the EVM to that snapshot at the end of your test, for example:

```
it("should not allow to buy tokens if crowdsale has finished", async function () {
    const snapshotId = web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_snapshot"});
    await timeTravel(100000); // Move forward in time so the crowdsale has finished
    await mineBlock(); // workaround for https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/336
    try {
        await crowdsale.buyTokens(accounts[1], {from:accounts[1], value: 1 * 10 ** 18});
    }
    catch (e) {
        web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_revert", params: [snapshotId]});
        return true;
    }
    throw new Error("I should never see this!");
});
```

BTW, this is exactly what `truffle test` does at the beginning and end of every `contract` clause (typically every JS file, though you can technically have several `contract` clauses in a single JS file) that it executes. So as an alternative to the solution above, you can simply put this specific test inside a `contract` clause:

```
contract("test", function(accounts) {
    it("should not allow to buy tokens if crowdsale has finished", async function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just made a simple PR for this. Works for me!

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/pull/95

Answer (score 0):

`evm_increaseTime` accepts negative numbers, so you can decrease time by invoking as follows:

```
// decrease time by 1 day
web3.currentProvider.send({
  jsonrpc: "2.0", 
  method: "evm_increaseTime", 
  params: [-1440], 
  id: 0
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to be working. Passing a negative number to evm_increaseTime does nothing. Not getting any errors but not going back either.